# Laravel Homestead No input file specified

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

at the moment I am having a real nightmare trying to get Laravel Homestead to work. Usually when I have had this issue on my work machine I simply run `vagrant provision` however on my personal machine when I run `vagrant provision` nothing really happens it just hangs for a few seconds and then it is ready for another command.

Here is my setup Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:

    - map: helloworld.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/HelloWorld/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

My host file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10 helloworld.app
```

When I run `vagrant up` I get no errors either. I just get `No input file specified.` when I visit the URL in my browser.

Has anybody had this issue before?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Is the casing for your `HelloWorld` directory correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a line break after the `sites:` parameter. If thats true, get rid of that and run `vagrant provision` again.

Make your `app/storage` writeable by your homestead user.

I do not know if this is the case or not but if you are starting / stoping VM via the GUI, it may behave differently. Using `vagrant <command>` is always better for things like `halt` etc.

Update:

Make sure nginx config in your VM mirrors what you have on your yaml config file for homestead. I mean the `public` is also pointed in the nginx configs so check files under `etc/ngnx/sites-available/` and make sure root points to where it is supposed to.

Update `app/storage` permissions with `chmod -R 777 app/storage`

Try running `homestead up --provision` it is `homestead` provision not vagrant.

You can [find more information here](https://laracasts.com/search?q=homestead&q-where=lessons) some of the tutorial vids might require a subscription but I know some stuff is free there. Just in case it might help.

Comment: I have removed the break and done the rest however I am still left with the same problem.

Comment: This usually happens to me when I have something weird with my Yaml file which causes web server to not be able to find index.php file. Yaml is very sensitive about tabs spacing etc. Do you have any tabs in the yaml file ? that may get wrongly interpreted as EOL or something. I am saying this because one time I replaced tabs with spaces then run `vagrant reload --provision` and it fixed it for me.

Comment: I have went into the Homestead directory and tried `vagrant up --provision`, still doesn't work.

Comment: If you are on Windows, restarting the entire box may help. Where does the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/homestead.app` in your homestead VM point to ? cat the file and look at the root pointer and make sure it is `.../public` .